# Which way is better for the azure application insights ? What are the pros and cons of each Auto-instrumentation and Application sdk way?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

Actually, I needed to enable the application insight in azure. I have applications on-prem and not hosted in the Azure. So which way can be better to start the process of insights. Auto-instrumentation(codeless) or by adding the application sdks in the C# app.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the same functionality whether you do auto-instrumentation (codeless) or through SDK. With the latter approach you also can start using SDK  for customizations down the road.